# update_attibute/update_attributes skip callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to update a field with array in after_save.

There are different other after_saves performing meanwhile, ignore this.

I tried using update_column, but it does not serialize array, so I need to get it work with update_attribute or update_attributes.

```
How can I update array to a single field without performing callbacks
```

Comment: A guy gave answer, and I said this is not I'm looking for. He just went and down voted all my questions!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ActiveRecord::Persistence#update_column(name, value)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column) and its companion [ActiveRecord::Persistence#update_columns(attributes)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns) are the methods to use if you want to skip callbacks and validations. From the class scope there is [ActiveRecord::Relation#update_all(updates)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all).
Alternatively you could go with JSON (instead of serializing the array) like:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  def foo= array
    write_attribute :foo, array.to_json
  end

  def foo
    JSON.parse(read_attribute :foo)
  end
end
```

and somewhere else:

```
Bar.first.update_column :foo, [1,2,3].to_json
```

At least, when you deal with serializing [ActiveRecord::Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) could be interesting for you.

Comment: This is really awesome. I had gone through ruby documentation, could not found solution. This is really very helpful. Thank you very much @tobago